# Event ID 7034 : The HP NIC Agent service terminated unexpectedly

Tags: hp

I have a server on which the HP Insight NIC Agent Service terminates unexpectedly on a random basis.
This stops the monitoring of the server sending out false alarms.

```
The event log is as below
--------------------------------------
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          XX/XX/XX
Event ID:      7034
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      XX.XX.XX
Description:
The HP Insight NIC Agents service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 3 time(s).
```

HP says that this ain't a hardware issue and I would need to check the registry. Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried checking the registry?

Comment: I am not sure where to start looking and what to look for in the registry...any ideas?

Comment: You should ask HP support that, they were the ones who told you to check the registry.

Comment: What model server is this? What version of the agents are you running?

Comment: What specific OS version, what else is going on, etc?  Your question isn't too much different from "my application keeps crashing, why?"

Comment: @HopelessN00b -The OS version is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1, Nothing else seems to be going on other than this issue

Comment: @womble: Hp does not know where to look

Comment: And what server model is it?

Comment: @ewwhite, Model is HP Proliant DL360 G7 HP agents version is 8.50.0.0

Comment: If they don't know where in the registry to look, when they told you to look in the registry, I wouldn't trust them when they say it isn't a hardware issue.  Escalate with HP support until you get to someone who knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the HP ProLiant Support Pack and system drivers you're running is as old as the server you're using. The version 8.50 of the management agents were released in May 2010, shortly after the release of G7 ProLiant servers.

I would suggest updating the firmware and drivers on the server to the current releases.

[All software for your OS and server type is available here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=4091409&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D4091409%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091408%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

As of this writing, the management agents are on [version 9.10](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091409&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Dlang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091408%257CprodNameId%253D4091409%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-63633e1bebe9431987c1ece85b%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). The [bootable firmware DVD for the system](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D4091412%257CprodNameId%253D4091432%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-d9b0fbede4e343bca7de3cdfdc%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) is available here. I'd recommend running the DVD during a 30-minute downtime period, then running the ProLiant Support Pack upgrade package. You can do this piecemeal by just installing the newer software, but I suspect that the system firmware is way out of date as well since you're on old drivers.

Comment: Well It's a surprise to me that HP did not mention anything of that sort, I guess I will just have to try the above then. Will update once I have been able to install the above ...Thanks all.